# Build complex layout in a dynamic list/grid

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I'm building a simple app with python3 and GTK3.0 looking for the correct element for display a layout like the following image

[image]

I need display N items this items are load from a database (can be 1000+) and can change (insert, delete, update, etc.) and each item have a complex layout inside (labels, buttons, etc.)

**How I can build a layout with a list/grid that dynamically changes.**

I've read about GtkTreeView and GtkCellRenderer but i dont know how and other people recommend use GtkBox but how handle a model and update dynamically like ListView/CursorAdapter in android or ListView/Bindings in C#/WPF.

[documentation of GTK 3.0](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) is really poor and does not explain how to extend a widget. another point that the documentation does not explain or at least I have not seen is how to reuse the same element, how to make good use of the resources (memory) when dealing with lots of elements, for example I created a series of widget in glade and I can not use N times. also not possible to create items that are not windows. everything should be within a window. as I can create a different arbitrary element of a window that can be reused.

please when you point me any of the above points, this has an example code can be C #, Python or C + + but it is important to have an example

Answer (score 1):

I've just create a project called 'sqlite-browser' using python3 and gtk.  When you display a large number of records in a database, you can use treeview, and add a pager (limit 100/200 records each page). Maybe this project can help you. And here it is: https://github.com/LiuLang/sqlite-browser

This is screenshot: [image]

Comment: Link is dead. Do you have another repo?